# Time Scheduling in Asp.Net using TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net project where doctor's have start time, end time and duration(All are saved as Time in mssql). In my models folder I have a **time_slots.cs** file which is supposed to make a list of slots.

I short this is what I want:

john doe : start time -> 08:00:00 end time -> 12:00:00 duration: 01:00:00

Result: 08:00:00, 09:00:00, 10:00:00 , 11:00:00 ,12:00:00

This is code I'm using:

```
namespace das.Models
{

    public class time_slot
    {
        public List<TimeSpan> TimeSlots(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, TimeSpan duration)
        {
            List<TimeSpan> slots = new List<TimeSpan>();

            TimeSpan ToAdd = TimeSpan.Zero;

            while(ToAdd < end)
            {
                ToAdd = start + end;
                slots.Add(ToAdd);
            }
            return slots;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show this slots as dropdown in my dashboard after the user logs in to make an appointment. How am I supposed to do that?
And is there any better and easier way to do this is asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a custom class for the output. Something like this:

```
public class slot
{
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string DisplayString
    {
        get
        {
            return StartTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + " - " + (StartTime + Duration).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        }
    }
    public slot(TimeSpan StartTime, TimeSpan Duration)
    {
        this.StartTime = StartTime;
        this.Duration = Duration;
    }
}
```

Then your TimeSlots code would look like this:

```
public List<slot> TimeSlots(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, TimeSpan duration)
{
    List<slot> slots = new List<slot>();
    while (start < end)
    {
        slots.Add(new slot(start, duration));
        start = start + duration;
    }
    return slots;
}
```

Now you have a list of "slot" objects, with a DisplayString property that you can format any way you want. And you could add a "Value" property if you need to, or just use the slot object itself.

Comment: So, I'll put both the TimeSlots method in slots.cs?
And how will I turn this list into a dropdown in cshtml?
should I access it in the controller and pass it as a parameter to the view?